# Exception when passing parameter in cdecl and pascal

Tags: c, parameter-passing, cdecl

```
void cdecl fun1(int,int);
void pascal fun2(int,int);
int main(){
  int a=5,b=5;

  fun1(a,++a);
  fun2(b,++b);
 return 0;
}
void cdecl fun1(int p,int q){
  printf("cdecl:  %d %d \n",p,q);
}
void pascal fun2(int p,int q){
  printf("pascal: %d %d",p,q);
}
```

> Error : :12: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âfun1â

Comment: I think `fun1(a,++a);` form is UB, anyway.

Comment: It appears your compiler doesn't understand `cdecl`. Did you mean __cdecl or something similar?

Comment: it could be even *__attribute__((__cdecl__))* - Check your compiler manual.